# PHP stream File from temp path?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

I have a PHP/JS fileupload and I want to stream a video before it is 100% uploaded.

How I make that?

fileupload.html (JS, uploadFile()):

```
var file = document.getElementById("file1").files[0];   
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file1", file);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
ajax.send(formdata);
```

fileupload.html (html)

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input class="fileUpload" type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
  <input id="uploadBtn" type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
</form>
```

file_upload_parser.php:

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"];

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName")){
    echo "complete";
}
?>
```

VideoStream.php:
https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293

streamer.php

```
<?php
    $path = $_GET['path'];
    include "VideoStream.php";
    $stream = new VideoStream($path); 
    $stream->start();exit;
?>

<video controls preload="auto" src="<?php echo $path ?>" width="100%"></video>
```

Comment: Do you want me to show you the way I do it?

Comment: Yes that would be really nice!

Comment: so what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so you want to show people a preview of what they choose before they upload the video.

**HTML & JavaScript Code**

```js
(function Preview_Video() {
 'use strict'
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
 
 
  var Play_Video = function (event) {
    var file = this.files[0]
    var type = file.type
    var videoNode = document.querySelector('video')
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    videoNode.src = fileURL
  }
  
  var inputNode = document.querySelector('input')
  inputNode.addEventListener('change', Play_Video, false)
})()
```

```html
<div id="video"></div>
<video controls autoplay></video>

<form method="POST" name="form">
<input type="file" name="media-vid" accept="video/*"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Just use this code and you will be good.

**Example picture from my website/screen:**
[image]